# Doctrine countDistinct alias

Tags: php, doctrine

How i can set an alias for a countDistinct expr using Doctrine queryBuilder?

```
$qb->addSelect($qb->expr()->countDistinct('_charges.id'));
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't. Here's what the [countDistinct function](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.2/source-class-Doctrine.ORM.Query.Expr.html#247) returns:

```
return 'COUNT(DISTINCT ' . implode(', ', func_get_args()) . ')';
```

You could however directly call the select function like this:

```
select('COUNT(DISTINCT _charges.id) AS charges')
```

Comment: Ok, so this is the solution:

    
    $qb->addSelect($qb->expr()->countDistinct('_charges.id') . ' AS ChargesCount');
    $qb->addSelect($qb->expr()->countDistinct('_invoices.id') . ' AS InvoicesCount');
    $qb->addSelect($qb->expr()->countDistinct('_services.id') . ' AS ServicesCount');